# Java parallel processes with fork

Tags: java, concurrency, process, parallel-processing, fork

I was wondering if it was possible in Java to create multiple processes (yes, processes, not threads) to do some parallel works. For example, to calculate the surface of five squares, but that calculation for each square must be done in separate process. It is supposed to use forking of processes, but I am new to concurrency in Java, so I don't really know how to do those things. If you could explain this to me, or direct me to the place or book that does, I would be very grateful. I have seen many Java books for concurrency, but only for threads and not processes.

Comment: what do _you_ think the distinction is between a thread and a process?

Comment: Version 7 has some new functionality, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch processes using the ProcessBuilder class, or the older Runtime.exec method. On Unix systems these use the fork and exec functions. You'll find the documentation of ProcessBuilder here, it includes an example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Probably you'll also want to know how two processes can talk to each other so that the results of the computation can be recovered. There are too many options to discuss any at length here. Popular ones are pipes, TCP sockets, memory mapped files, and message queues.